# Change Kernel version under option in GRUB

Tags: kernel, dual-boot, grub

I have dual boot configuration with Windows 10 and Debian. For Debian I have multiple kernels installed and as a "main" grub suggest the newest one and lists olders in "Advanced options for Debian GNU/Linux". Now, I'd like to have Windows as default option selected on computer start but also some older kernel under the main Debian in menu. How can I achieve that?

I found information with editing `GRUB_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub` but this is set as following:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/nvme0n1p1)"
```

That's the part I don't want to edit but as a result after `update-grub` I want to have `menuentry` pointing to version 4.9 instead of 4.18. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add new script to `/etc/grub.d/` directory or edit the existing rule (`10_linux` most probably in your case). However, please be aware that those automatic tools have some limitations, so I'm pretty sure that if you start playing with grub configuration sooner or later you will end-up editing `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` directly, as a most flexible method.

---

If you are fine with adding new menu entry for particular kernel then probably the easiest is to edit `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` and add something like

```
menuentry "Kernel 4.9" {
    set root='hd0,gpt2'
    linux /vmlinuz-4.9 root=/dev/sda1 ro init=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd 
}
```

Change settings and kernel parameters to yours, look at your current `grub.cfg` to check them. You may also need to add other lines like `initrd` or get rid of `systemd` if you don't use it.

Comment: And how should this `10_linux` look alike? I mean, I thought of editing `grub.cfg` and disabling regeneration but I'd like to avoid it for now just in case. Alternatively to changing behavior of current Debian option in menu I would be also fine with adding another one that would run older kernel...

Comment: Yes, adding another menu entry is probably the easiest if you don't want to modify grub.cfg. I edited the answer to add same basic example.